# List images created by Docker for Mac using Docker Toolbox

Tags: docker, docker-toolbox, docker-for-mac

From Docker's [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/docker-toolbox/#/docker-toolbox-and-docker-for-mac-coexistence), I read both *Docker for Mac* and the *Docker Toolbox* can coexist.

So I thought I could use these images created by `Docker for Mac`, but when I switched to `Docker Toolbox`, it turned out that I was wrong, because I entered `docker images` in `Docker Quickstart Terminal.app` and no image was listed.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker-for-Mac sets up a small virtual machine via hyperkit, which is a xhyve-based virtualization solution.

The quickstart terminal also sets up a small virtual machine, but it uses the docker-machine tool to create a virtualbox VM.

Both of these approaches are valid approaches to get a running Docker-in-a-vm-on-your-mac, but *they are different VMs*.

Similarly, if I have a regular linux machine at my desk, and I pull an image, you won't see that image in the docker daemon on the linux machine at your desk.

Both tools can coexist, but they don't share data.

Answer (score 0):

You can't share images directly between Docker for Mac and Docker Toolbox. They are two different and independent systems.

In Docker for Mac, the docker daemon is running inside an Alpine linux vm controlled by a small hypervisor (Xhyve). In Docker Toolbox, the docker daemon runs inside a boot2docker vm controlled by VirtualBox.

Comment: ^.^, same answer as @programmerq, and I konw this essentials about them. so the answer is **NO WAY**ha . Thanks.

Comment: @KaiyuLee There was no answer when I started writing mine. He clicked the submit button before I did. That happens.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly communicate between the two, but you can save the image using `docker save` ([documentation here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/)):

```
docker save image_from_dockertoolbox > toolbox.tar
```

and then use `docker load` ([documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/load/)) to load it after changing to docker4mac:

```
docker load < toolbox.tar.gz
```

Comment: :) I  know the way to transfer images between different servers(hosts), thanks any way!